# J2me implementation for linux or other

Tags: java, java-me

I'm searching for information on how to create a j2me implementation. My target is a generic linux host... does it exist already? I mean a way to run j2me applications on linux without an emulator? Do you know where to find info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do you want to do this?

the only reason I ask is j2me applications are designed for mobile devices. This means that you wont be able to run j2me applications on a standard computer without an emulator of somekind?!?

when making j2me apps in linux, the netbeans emulator has had everything I've ever needed

Comment: The new Nokia N900 uses Maemo5 as its operating system which is based on Debian and thus is a fully-fledged Linux phone. Similarly Google's Android is also based on Linux. Neither of these support midlets which is a huge step backwards from previous phones.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [phoneME project](https://phoneme.dev.java.net/). It's not officially supported but it does run under Linux.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might be made to do what you want:

http://www.microemu.org/

It's open source, so you can take it, tweak it, and make it run where you want.

Comment: The link is broken